# Teradata Unity and Session ID

Tags: teradata

I need to develop a code to check the Teradata TCP packet to read the SessionID and check information about the session.

With the SessioID I obtained, I want to do a query like this:

`SELECT * FROM DBC.SESSIONINF WHERE SESSIONNO = <session_id>`

The Teradata I'm working on uses Unity that modifies the TCP packet with a SessionID different from the one in the DB.

So the query above returns zero rows.

I think I can ask the DBA to change the Unity routing rules to Passive Routing, but I want to be sure that with this configuration, Unity doesn't change the SessionID.

Do you have any experience with Unity and its routing rules?

Comment: There's a built-in `SESSION` which returns the current session number. `SELECT * FROM DBC.SESSIONINFOV WHERE SESSIONNO = SESSION` be what you want.

Comment: Thanks, @dnoeth, but I have to read the SessionID from the TCP packet.

Comment: Even with passive routing, the Unity session ID (between client and Unity) won't be the same as the corresponding proxy session ID (between Unity and the database).